# Is any possibility to validate method content?

Tags: java

I am trying to create some kind of rest assured automation framework

I've got class hierarchy like:

```
public abstract class RestTestTemplate<TestClass extends RestTestTemplate> {

public RestTestTemplate request() {} // this is a method to initialize request, it has to be always the first method in test

public RestTestTemplate pathParam (String field, Object value) {}  // this is a method to set path parameters
}
```

and subclass

```
public class GetBooksTest extends RestTestTemplate<GetBookTests> {

@Test
public void myFirstTest(){
request()
.pathParam("id",23)
}
```

My question is if I can validate  that every method in class GetBooksTest starts with request() method?
I would like to prevent someone from writing test like

```
pathParam("id",23)
.request()
```

or the only option is to move "pathParam" method to another class?

Thanks

Comment: You can make the methods final and call protected methods with the implementation from there; that way, you can check method order. But I have doubts that your concept is useful to begin with, since inheritance is usually not useful in this kind of situations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the only option is to have `request()` return a new class, (a `Request` class of some sort) and then make `pathParam()` a member of that new class. It makes sense.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but my goal was to have RestTestTemplate class abstract. If I return some new class in method `request()` then this new class cannot be abstract, am I right? I wanted to prevent from creating new instances of RestTestTemplate  class.

Comment: The class that eventually provides the implementation of `RestTestTemplate` will need to also provide the implementation of that `Request` class. Possibly by making use of the factory pattern to accomplish this.